# Login does nothing in Spring, neither goes on home page nor denies request

Tags: java, spring

I am new to programming, my code is not perfect, for sure.I  will try to be brief and clear.

Login worked fine until I added Register page. It worked with "user" and "admin", they had roles, everything was fine.

Now, I have Register page. User can register and he becomes a "member". When I list members I can see that he is in database. But when he tries to login with his username and password, nothing happens. He doesn't become a "user" and he can do nothing. Also, when trying to login with old "user/user" or "admin/admin"(before adding Register page worked fine), nothing happens. There isn't even a message "invalid username or password", as it was before. It simply clears the fields "username" and "password" and they become `null`.

Here is **User:**

```
@Entity                                                                 
public class AppUser extends AbstractDomainClass{

private Long userId;
private String username;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private boolean enabled;
private String email;
@Transient
private String encrytedPassword;


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable
// ~ defaults to @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
//     inverseJoinColumns = @joinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
private Integer failedLoginAttempts = 0;



public AppUser() {

}

public AppUser(Long userId, String userName, String firstName, String lastName, //
        boolean enabled,  //
        String email, String encrytedPassword) {
    super();
    this.userId = userId;
    this.username = userName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.email = email;
    this.encrytedPassword = encrytedPassword;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return username;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.username = userName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEncrytedPassword() {
    return encrytedPassword;
}

public void setEncrytedPassword(String encrytedPassword) {
    this.encrytedPassword = encrytedPassword;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public void addRole(Role role){
    if(!this.roles.contains(role)){
        this.roles.add(role);
    }

    if(!role.getUsers().contains(this)){
        role.getUsers().add(this);
    }
}

public void removeRole(Role role){
    this.roles.remove(role);
    role.getUsers().remove(this);
}

public Integer getFailedLoginAttempts() {
    return failedLoginAttempts;
}

public void setFailedLoginAttempts(Integer failedLoginAttempts) {
   this.failedLoginAttempts = failedLoginAttempts;
```

**AppUserDAO** (Tom&Jerry are loaded, but they can't login in!)

```
@Repository 
public class AppUserDAO {

// Config in WebConfig
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

private static final Map<Long, AppUser> USERS_MAP = new HashMap<>();

static {
    initDATA();
}

private static void initDATA() {
    String encrytedPassword = "";

    AppUser tom = new AppUser(1L, "tom", "Tom", "Tom", //
            true,  "tom@waltdisney.com", encrytedPassword);

    AppUser jerry = new AppUser(2L, "jerry", "Jerry", "Jerry", //
            true, "jerry@waltdisney.com", encrytedPassword);

    USERS_MAP.put(tom.getUserId(), tom);
    USERS_MAP.put(jerry.getUserId(), jerry);
}

public Long getMaxUserId() {
    long max = 0;
    for (Long id : USERS_MAP.keySet()) {
        if (id > max) {
            max = id;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

//

public AppUser findAppUserByUserName(String userName) {
    Collection<AppUser> appUsers = USERS_MAP.values();
    for (AppUser u : appUsers) {
        if (u.getUserName().equals(userName)) {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public AppUser findAppUserByEmail(String email) {
    Collection<AppUser> appUsers = USERS_MAP.values();
    for (AppUser u : appUsers) {
        if (u.getEmail().equals(email)) {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public List<AppUser> getAppUsers() {
    List<AppUser> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.addAll(USERS_MAP.values());
    return list;
}

public AppUser createAppUser(AppUserForm form) {
    Long userId = this.getMaxUserId() + 1;
    String encrytedPassword = this.passwordEncoder.encode(form.getPassword());

    AppUser user = new AppUser(userId, form.getUserName(), //
            form.getFirstName(), form.getLastName(), false, //
            form.getEmail(),  //
            encrytedPassword);

    USERS_MAP.put(userId, user);
    return user;
}
```

**SpringSecurityConfiguration:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SpringSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider")
public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
    this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
}

/*@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor){
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new PasswordEncoder();
    passwordEncoder.setPasswordEncryptor(passwordEncryptor);
    return passwordEncoder;
}*/

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService){

    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Autowired
public void configureAuthManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder){
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/events", "/event/show/*", "/console/**").authenticated()
    //.anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().permitAll()
    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register", "/login","/members").permitAll();


    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

**SpringJpaBootstrap** (Events are loaded, but not users!)

```
@Component
public class SpringJpaBootstrap implements 
ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

private EventRepository eventRepository;
private UserService userService;
private RoleService roleService;

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SpringJpaBootstrap.class);

@Autowired
public void setEventRepository(EventRepository eventRepository) {
    this.eventRepository = eventRepository;
}

@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Autowired
public void setRoleService(RoleService roleService) {
    this.roleService = roleService;
}


@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    loadEvents();
    loadUsers();
    loadRoles();
    assignUsersToUserRole();
    assignUsersToAdminRole();
}

private void loadEvents() {

    Event conference = new Event();

    conference.setEventName("Java Brain");
    conference.setCreatedBy("Milan Gutovic");
    conference.setStartingDate("23.5.2018.");
    conference.setStartingTime("12.00.");
    conference.setPlace("Crown Plaza");
    conference.setId(457);
    eventRepository.save(conference);

    log.info("Saved Conference - id: " + conference.getId());

    Event meeting = new Event();

    meeting.setEventName("GetTogether");
    meeting.setCreatedBy("Jeremy Brown");
    meeting.setStartingDate("25.8.2019.");
    meeting.setStartingTime("15.00.");
    meeting.setPlace("Hilton");
    meeting.setId(458);
    eventRepository.save(meeting);

    log.info("Saved Meeting - id: " + meeting.getId());
}

private void loadUsers() {
    AppUser user1 = new AppUser();
    user1.setUserId(2L);
    user1.setUserName("user");
    user1.setEncrytedPassword("user");
    user1.setFirstName("Nemanja");
    user1.setLastName("Balaban");
    user1.setEnabled(true);
    user1.setEmail("user@gmail.com");
    user1.setEncrytedPassword("123");
    userService.saveOrUpdate(user1);

   /* AppUser user2 = new AppUser();
    user2.setUserName("admin");
    user2.setEncrytedPassword("admin");
    userService.saveOrUpdate(user2);*/

}

private void loadRoles() {

    Role role = new Role();
    role.setRole("USER");
    roleService.saveOrUpdate(role);
    log.info("Saved role" + role.getRole());
    Role adminRole = new Role();
    adminRole.setRole("ADMIN");
    roleService.saveOrUpdate(adminRole);
    log.info("Saved role" + adminRole.getRole());
}
private void assignUsersToUserRole() {
    List<Role> roles = (List<Role>) roleService.listAll();
    List<AppUser> users = (List<AppUser>) userService.listAll();

    roles.forEach(role -> {
        if (role.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("USER")) {
            users.forEach(user -> {
                if (user.getUserName().equals("user")) {
                    user.addRole(role);
                    userService.saveOrUpdate(user);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
private void assignUsersToAdminRole() {
    List<Role> roles = (List<Role>) roleService.listAll();
    List<AppUser> users = (List<AppUser>) userService.listAll();

    roles.forEach(role -> {
        if (role.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")) {
            users.forEach(user -> {
                if (user.getUserName().equals("admin")) {
                    user.addRole(role);
                    userService.saveOrUpdate(user);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**MainController**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private AppUserDAO appUserDAO;



@Autowired
private AppUserValidator appUserValidator;

// Set a form validator
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    // Form target
    Object target = dataBinder.getTarget();
    if (target == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Target=" + target);

    if (target.getClass() ==  AppUserForm.class) {
        dataBinder.setValidator(appUserValidator);
    }

}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String viewHome(Model model) {

    return "welcomePage";
}

@RequestMapping("/members")
public String viewMembers(Model model) {

    List<AppUser> list = appUserDAO.getAppUsers();

    model.addAttribute("members", list);

    return "membersPage";
}

@RequestMapping("/registerSuccessful")
public String viewRegisterSuccessful(Model model) {

    return "registerSuccessfulPage";
}

// Show Register page.
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewRegister(Model model) {

    AppUserForm form = new AppUserForm();
    model.addAttribute( "appUserForm", form);
    return "registerPage";
}

// This method is called to save the registration information.
// @Validated: To ensure that this Form
// has been Validated before this method is invoked.
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRegister(Model model, //
        @ModelAttribute("appUserForm") @Validated AppUserForm appUserForm, //
        BindingResult result, //
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    // Validate result
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registerPage";
    }

    AppUser newUser= null;
    try {
        newUser = appUserDAO.createAppUser(appUserForm);
    }
    // Other error!!
    catch (Exception e) {

    }

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashUser", newUser);

    return "redirect:/registerSuccessful";
}

}
```

**Role**

```
@Entity
public class Role extends AbstractDomainClass {

private String role;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable

private List<AppUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public List<AppUser> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<AppUser> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public void addUser(AppUser user){
    if(!this.users.contains(user)){
        this.users.add(user);
    }

    if(!user.getRoles().contains(this)){
        user.getRoles().add(this);
    }
}

public void removeUser(AppUser user){
    this.users.remove(user);
    user.getRoles().remove(this);
}

}
```

**RoleServiceJpaImpl**

```
@Service
@Profile("jpadao")
public class RoleServiceJpaImpl extends AbstractJpaDaoService implements 
RoleService {

@Override
public List<?> listAll() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    return em.createQuery("from Role", Role.class).getResultList();
}

@Override
public Role getById(Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    return em.find(Role.class, id);
}

@Override
public Role saveOrUpdate(Role domainObject) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Role saveRole = em.merge(domainObject);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return saveRole;
}
```

**UserServiceJpaDAOImpl**

```
@Service
@Profile("jpadao")
public class UserServiceJpaDaoImpl extends AbstractJpaDaoService implements 
UserService {

private EncryptionService encryptionService;

@Autowired
public void setEncryptionService(EncryptionService encryptionService) {
    this.encryptionService = encryptionService;
}

@Override
public List<?> listAll() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    return em.createQuery("from User", AppUser.class).getResultList();
}

@Override
public AppUser getById(Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    return em.find(AppUser.class, id);
}

@Override
public AppUser saveOrUpdate(AppUser domainObject) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    if(domainObject.getEncrytedPassword() != null){
        domainObject.setEncrytedPassword(encryptionService.encryptString(domainObject.getEncrytedPassword()));
    }

    AppUser saveduser = em.merge(domainObject);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return saveduser;
}

@Override
public void delete(Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(em.find(AppUser.class, id));
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}

@Override
public AppUser findAppUserByUsername(String userName) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    return em.createQuery("from User where userName = :userName", 
AppUser.class).setParameter("userName", userName).getSingleResult();
}
}
```

**UserDetailsImpl**

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities;
private String userName;
private String password;
private Boolean enabled = true;

public void setAuthorities(Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public void setEncrytedPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return userName;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}


}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@Profile("springdatajpa")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

private EncryptionService encryptionService;

@Autowired
public void setEncryptionService(EncryptionService encryptionService) {
    this.encryptionService = encryptionService;
}


@Override
public List<?> listAll() {
    List<AppUser> users = new ArrayList<>();
    userRepository.findAll().forEach(users::add); 
    return users;
}

@Override
public AppUser getById(Integer id) {
    return userRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public AppUser saveOrUpdate(AppUser domainObject) {
    if(domainObject.getEncrytedPassword() != null){
        domainObject.setEncrytedPassword(encryptionService.encryptString(domainObject.getEncrytedPassword()));
    }
    return userRepository.save(domainObject);
}
@Override
@Transactional
   public void delete(Integer id) {
    userRepository.delete(id);
}

@Override
public AppUser findAppUserByUsername(String userName) {
    return userRepository.findAppUserByUsername(userName);
}
}
```

**RepositoryConfiguration**

```
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = 
{"nemanja.springframework.domain","nemanja.springframework.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = 
{"nemanja.springframework.repositories"})
@EnableTransactionManagement

public class RepositoryConfiguration {

}
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
<title>Login Form</title>
<!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> /*/-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->
<div th:if="${param.error}">
<label> <font size="4" color="red">Invalid username and password. </font> 
</label>
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
<label> <font size="4" color="red">
You have been logged out.</font>
</label>
</div>

<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td><label><font size="4"> User Name : </font><input type="text" 
  name="username"/> </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><font size="4"> Password :</font> <input type="password" 
  name="password"/> </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><font size="5" 
 color="black">Sign In</font></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it my Repository, Configuration, Mapping, html?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: have you hosted the entire source code somewhere? Like `github.com`?
I was thinking to try executing it.

Comment: Shreyas, thank you for your time and effort. The code is here: https://github.com/Nemanjone/practice/tree/master/SpringBootEventsGeckoApplication